# Skipping a loop in foreach?

Tags: unity, game-loop

I'm trying to get Unity to filter through a list of nodes, but I am unsure on how to do so. This is what I have derived.

```
foreach (TileNode z in map.nodes)
        {
            int num = TileNode z;
            if(num%2==0){
                continue;
            }

            z.collider.enabled = true;
        }
```

However an error prompt states that 'z' is an unexpected symbol. Any advice on the proper syntax to deal with this will be greatly appreciated.

Also, an example of how do peform filtering using LINQ will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
int num = TileNode z;
```

You are declaring a `TileNode` with symbol `z`, but you are assigning that to an `int`.  You can't assign a symbol declaration under any circumstances, so the compiler is yelling at you for it.  It also doesn't make any sense; you probably want to assign that `int` to some property of `z`, right?

This is doubly wrong because you already declared that same symbol in the foreach loop, though the above line would be wrong regardless.

---

The linq syntax is exactly as you wrote it, except you change your conditional statement into a nearly-identical lambda expression.  [You can read all about them here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)